# How to convert between 1200 and 1200/75 baud devices? socat?

Tags: serial-port, socat

Is it possible to get a program that uses symmetrical 1200 baud to communicate over serial to a device running at 1200/75? I've tried putting socet in between to create a virtual serial device running at 1200 and set the USB serial to 1200/75 but the far end still gets garbled text:

```
socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyvirt,raw,nonblock,echo=0,perm=0777,b1200 open:/dev/ttyUSB0,raw,nonblock,echo=0,ospeed=b1200,ispeed=b75
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question isn't exactly clear and appears that it doesn't fit SO well, and would probably fit better on [su]. If you are asking about writing code to accomplish that, then you need to research, try writing code, then ask a specific question about a particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ispeed and ospeed options take integer numbers as argument, so try without the 'b' prefixes!